In-place upgrading SQL Server 2019 to 2022
I am upgrading SQL Server 2019 Developer Edition to 2022. It is a supported upgrade path.
During installation, the following appears:

The path is non-existent.
The setup comes with a similar package, but if I select that, I get another error:

I have downloaded the latest from here: the official page with the same result.
I suppose by now, that it is trying to reach out to the original versions installer. But that was deleted.
I have searched through the registry for the nsvEFDE.tmp fragment but to no avail.
I have this version installed:

But even when downloading that specific version from the source, the error message is the same.
How can I solve this?
How can I determine the exact version it is looking for?
[Update]
I have manually uninstalled the one from the control panel without issues. After restarting the machine, I was able to proceed with the installation. This is only a workaround though. It might not be strictly an issue related to the SQL Server installer, but one of the installation infrastructure of Windows itself, but it still is a package related to the product. It could be more helpful in some shape or form.
